# Regex to Replace word preceded by specific word

Tags: c#, regex

So I'm trying to find a Regex to replace a word in all sentence starts with a specific word ( declare in my case)

> Example :
>
> declare @order int
>
> declare @order2 int

Comment: Not too sure what you're asking here...

Comment: Sorry, the question is unclear. Do you mean you need to replace all `@word`s if a string starts with `declare`? Then use `if (s.StartsWith("declare")) {/* run Regex.Replace or whatever */}`

Comment: Actually I need to find all the lines that starts with declare somthing and replace them with declare somthing2

Comment: I am afraid without your code it is hard to understand what goes wrong.

Comment: So, do you need help? If yes, please update the question. If not, please consider removing the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var lines = new string[]
{
    "declare @order int",
    "test string",
    "declare @order2 int"
};

string pattern = "declare";
string replacement = "something";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);

var output = lines.Select(l => l = (l.StartsWith(pattern)) ? 
                                      regex.Replace(l, replacement, 1) : l);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but I think you can use: `/declare (@order)/g`

I have tested this in Javascript wich gives:

```
var regex = /declare (@order)/g
var result1 = regex.exec("origin: test @order int");
// result: null

var regex = /declare (@order)/g
var result1 = regex.exec("result: declare  @order int");
// result: ["declare @order", "@order"]
```

You can use the regex in the str.replace function:

```
var str = "result: declare @order int";
var res = str.replace(/declare (@order)/g, "new-value");
// Result: "result: new-value int"
```